# How to hide elements depending on the state of radio buttons with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I have a data entry form on my site which contains multiple checkboxes, two radio buttons and a text fields. I want to make the text field show if "cheque" radio buttons is selected and hide that text box with value of Cheque text box's if "cash" radio button is selected.

The radio buttons and text area are as follows:

```
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="300">Balance Amount:</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
             <input  type="number" class="k-textbox" name="balance_amount" id="balance_amount" placeholder=""  size="30" value=" <?php echo $balance_amount; ?>" readonly ></input>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="300">Mode Of Payement :</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
         Cheque :<input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" id="cheq" value="1" >

        Cash :<input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" id="cash" value="2" checked >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bankName">
        <td valign="top" width="300">Bank Name :</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input  type="text" class="k-textbox" name="bank_name" id="bank_name" placeholder=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="branch">
        <td valign="top" width="300">Branch :</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input  type="text" class="k-textbox" name="branch_name" id="branch_name" placeholder="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Acc_No">
        <td valign="top" width="300">Account No :</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input  type="text" class="k-textbox"  name="account_no" id="account_no" placeholder="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="chq_no">

        <td valign="top" width="300">Cheque No</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
          <input type="number" id="cheque_number" name="cheque_number" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Enter Cheque No" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="chq_date">

        <td valign="top" width="300">Cheque Date</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input id="cheque_date" name="cheque_date" value="<?php echo $cheque_date; ?>"  type="text" ></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="pay_at">

        <td valign="top" width="300">Payable At</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input id="payable_at" name="payable_at"  class="k-textbox" type="text" ></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td valign="top" width="300">Paid Amount</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
          <input type="number" id="paid_amount" name="paid_amount" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Enter Digit" required validationMessage="Please Enter the Amount"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td valign="top" width="300">Amount In Words</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
          <input type="number" id="amount_in_words" name="amount_in_words" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Enter Words" required validationMessage="Please Enter Amount In Words"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Okay, this shows the HTML form, but you have tagged this javascript and jquery. Yes, you will likely use some javascript to solve this, but have you actually tried anything?

Comment: how about javascript/jquery?

Comment: i have tried javascript to hide text boxes.. Eg: if user click on cheque button and fills all details, but if user change his mind and click on cash button then the details of cheques should remove from text boxes as soon as it hide. And if he again click on cheque then the text boxes should be blank. I hope you understand my query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name=mode_of_payment]').change(function () {
            $('#chq_no').toggle(this.checked && this.value == 1);
            $('#chq_date').toggle(this.checked && this.value == 1);
        }).change();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a change handler for the radio buttons.

Also add a class `cheque` to the cheque specific rows like

```
<tr id="chq_no" class="cheque">

    <td valign="top" width="300">Cheque No</td>
    <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
        <input type="number" id="cheque_number" name="cheque_number" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Enter Cheque No" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="chq_date" class="cheque">

    <td valign="top" width="300">Cheque Date</td>
    <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
        <input id="cheque_date" name="cheque_date" value="<?php echo $cheque_date; ?>"  type="text" ></input></td>
</tr>
```

then

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('input[name="mode_of_payment"]').change(function(){
        $('.cheque').toggle(this.checked && this.value==1)
    }).change()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QnyX6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#chq_no").hide();
    $("#chq_date").hide();          

    $(":radio").click(function(e) {


        switch($(this).val()){

            case "1":
                $("#chq_no").show();
                $("#chq_date").show();
            break;

            case "2":
                $("#chq_no").hide();
                $("#chq_date").hide();          
            break;
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
        <td valign="top" width="300">Balance Amount:</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
             <input  type="number" class="k-textbox" name="balance_amount" id="balance_amount" placeholder=""  size="30" value=" <?php echo $balance_amount; ?>" readonly ></input>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="300">Mode Of Payement :</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
         Cheque :<input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" id="cheq" value="1" >

        Cash :<input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" id="cash" value="2" checked >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bankName">
        <td valign="top" width="300">Bank Name :</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input  type="text" class="k-textbox" name="bank_name" id="bank_name" placeholder=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="branch">
        <td valign="top" width="300">Branch :</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input  type="text" class="k-textbox" name="branch_name" id="branch_name" placeholder="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Acc_No">
        <td valign="top" width="300">Account No :</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input  type="text" class="k-textbox"  name="account_no" id="account_no" placeholder="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="chq_no">

        <td valign="top" width="300">Cheque No</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
          <input type="number" id="cheque_number" name="cheque_number" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Enter Cheque No" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="chq_date">

        <td valign="top" width="300">Cheque Date</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input id="cheque_date" name="cheque_date" value="<?php echo $cheque_date; ?>"  type="text" ></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="pay_at">

        <td valign="top" width="300">Payable At</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
            <input id="payable_at" name="payable_at"  class="k-textbox" type="text" ></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td valign="top" width="300">Paid Amount</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
          <input type="number" id="paid_amount" name="paid_amount" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Enter Digit" required validationMessage="Please Enter the Amount"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td valign="top" width="300">Amount In Words</td>
        <td valign="top" width="300" align="left">
          <input type="number" id="amount_in_words" name="amount_in_words" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Enter Words" required validationMessage="Please Enter Amount In Words"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the complete solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to try show() and hide() function of java script and also use Css property like display:block and display:hidden for hide and show text box. 
@namrata shrivas